# Using GRUNT from NodeJS error message "'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

The webproject that I am working on uses SASS which is compiled into Grunt tasks, and grunt is supposed to run in NodeJS.

I have been given these instructions but it's not working:

[image: img]

I installed NodeJS (default folder/settings)

I then went in my project folder in CMD `C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\officeincambridge>`

Then ran the command `npm install -g grunt-cli`
and `npm install grunt`

If I type NPM version (in dir above) I get `npm --version: 1.4.14` , `node --version: v0.10.29`

However, when if I try and compile the files using `grunt sass` i get this error message `'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

Can anyone assist me on how to use it (I have never used grunt before). [HERE](http://doc.osclass.org/How_to_modify_Bender_theme) are the instructions which I am using.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a duplicate of this question: [Grunt on Windows 8: 'grunt' is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135561/grunt-on-windows-8-grunt-is-not-recognized)

In his case, it was a PATH issue. Check that your PATH is correct. It must contains the path where npm is installed: `C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Comment: thank you the the reply. turns out restarting cmd and running npm install command did the trick. Thanks and sorry for duplicating the question!

Answer (score 5):

Try to install 
npm install -g grunt-cli

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue :
To Solve this
I have added "grunt path" in SYSTEM environment Variable .
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt

To find your grunt path Use Command(in cmd) : where grunt

Once Added Path to SYSTEM Environment Variable Restart Jenkins and build job again