# Cant use grunt on Windows 8

Tags: gruntjs

I am trying to use grunt on my new windows 8 machine, which is not working. Here's the problem.

```
c:\Users\User\Documents\Source\Project>npm install -g grunt
grunt@0.4.5 C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt
├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── eventemitter2@0.4.14
├── which@1.0.5
├── getobject@0.1.0
├── colors@0.6.2
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── async@0.1.22
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0
├── exit@0.1.2
├── lodash@0.9.2
├── coffee-script@1.3.3
├── underscore.string@2.2.1
├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
├── grunt-legacy-log@0.1.1 (underscore.string@2.3.3, lodash@2.4.1)
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.0, graceful-fs@1.2.3)
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.5.0)
├── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.1, glob@3.2.11)
└── js-yaml@2.0.5 (esprima@1.0.4, argparse@0.1.15)

c:\Users\User\Documents\Source\Project>grunt
'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I'm trying to look for grunt.cmd which I cannot find anywhere in my system. Is somebody else facing this problem too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grunt on Windows 8: 'grunt' is not recognized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135561/grunt-on-windows-8-grunt-is-not-recognized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing grunt-cli and see if that fixes your problem:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```