# grunt not installing/available globally

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to install grunt globally using the following command from the command line:

npm install -g grunt

The installation command seems to succeed with no errors written to the console.  However, when I enter grunt at the command line after install I get the following error:

'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

It looks like the install command installs grunt into the following directory by default:

c:\users\my_login_id\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt

Not sure if the user-specific install directory might have anything to do with the issue?  Any idea what might be causing the problem or how to debug?

Comment: Almost always the problem in this case is related to paths.  Is the `appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules` in your `PATH`?  If not...adding it will likely be the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grunt on Windows 8: 'grunt' is not recognized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135561/grunt-on-windows-8-grunt-is-not-recognized)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install grunt globally.  I suggest you make grunt a dependency of your project.  That way anyone can execute a npm install and get grunt.  If you want to use the terminal commands, then you must install the command line interface package

Use:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```