# 'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command for some windows users

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Grunt is not working for all Windows users. Some users are facing some issues, when I run `npm install` command; it prints a message as below.

```
E:\Worksapce\web>npm install
npm WARN package.json registers@4.0.0 No repository field.
```

When I tried `npm install -g grunt-cli`, I think it is successful.

```
E:\Worksapce\web>npm install -g grunt-cli
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt -> C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt
grunt-cli@0.1.13 C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli
+-- resolve@0.3.1
+-- nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
+-- findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.1, glob@3.2.11)
```

But when I run grunt, I get an error message like this:

```
E:\Worksapce\web>
E:\Worksapce\web>grunt
'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My package.json is this.

```
{
  "author": "Company",
  "name": "registers",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "homepage": "http://abcd.se",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.4",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-ngmin": "0.0.3",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "~0.5.2"
  }
}
```

Another user is succesfully able to execute grunt with out any issues. This only stands for some of the users.

Can some one tell me what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Grunt is no longer installed globally. See the [Getting Started](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) page for more information.

The command below should help you fix this;

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Comment: The problem is that grunt is no longer installed globally (see also the starting guide: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) and for this reason, this answer counts.

Answer (score 22):

Your logs indicate that the `grunt` command was created in your global directory.  The errors also indicate that `C:\Users\mc862634\AppData\Roaming\npm\` is not in your path.

You'll want to check your `PATH` and make sure that the `\AppData\Roaming\npm` location is added if it is missing.

The easiest way to check is to open a command prompt and type `PATH`.

See this other StackOverflow question as a reference: [Grunt on Windows 8: 'grunt' is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135561/grunt-on-windows-8-grunt-is-not-recognized)

Answer (score 17):

On Windows 8, Grunt needs to have the following added to the `PATH`:

```
C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

On some systems, the number of characters allowable in the PATH is limited, and this can cause the correct path needed by grunt to not be added, even after `npm install -g grunt-cli` is run. Some settings (for example for certain programs you have installed) can be safely removed from the PATH, as they're generally there as a failsafe and often aren't required. If you have this issue:

- Backup the variables in your `PATH` (This PC > right-click > Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables > 'Edit' the 'Path' user variables for the current user, and copy the 'Variable value' and save it somewhere)
- Remove some of the values from the `PATH`, and add in the path `C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Also, make sure that after installing the Grunt CLI and adding the path, that you close any open command windows and re-open them before trying a `Grunt`

Comment: Problem solved! those steps worked also on Windows 10

Answer (score 4):

`Grunt-CLI` is installed inside %AppData%\npm, so the best directory to add to your `%PATH%` is:

```
%AppData%\npm
```

Answer (score 2):

npm install grunt -g (or) npm install -g grunt-cli
Please check your computer environmental variable path, it should contain the path of AppData. EX: E:\$APPDATA\npm\;

MyComputer->Right click-> Properties ->Advances System Setting-> Environment Variables -> Path

Answer (score 1):

Incase that there some developer that used Windows XP, that have similar problem you'll need to change **Path** entry.

**From**:
C:\Users\change_username\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt

**To**:
C:\Documents and Settings\change_username\Application Data\npm