# Node JS https proxy issues

Tags: node.js, npm-install, econnreset

I am facing issues in **'npm install grunt-cli'**.Below is the trace from debug log.

```
31 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
32 error argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
33 error node v4.4.4
34 error npm  v2.15.1
35 error code ENOTFOUND
36 error errno ENOTFOUND
37 error syscall getaddrinfo
38 error network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:80
```

**Machine**: Windows 7
**Node JS details**: npm@2.15.1/node@v4.4.4
I already tried below posts:

- ['grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command for some windows users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365377/grunt-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-for-some-windows-us)
- [npm not working - "read ECONNRESET"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset)
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8151

Comment: Have you access to https://registry.npmjs.org/ ? From your browser for example.

Comment: The problem was related to proxy url.Also I added npm registry url,which solved the issue,