# Express.JS installed globally isn't found on Windows

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I have tried installing express-generator via global but it's not found.

I have tried opening a new CMD / Powershell and same thing happens.

```
PS C:\Users\testuser\testme> npm install -g express-generator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs.commandline.0.10.31\tools\express -> C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\
lib\nodejs.commandline.0.10.31\tools\node_modules\express-generator\bin\express
express-generator@4.9.0 C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs.commandline.0.10.31\tools\node_modules\
express-generator
├── commander@1.3.2 (keypress@0.1.0)
└── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
PS C:\Users\testuser\testme> express
express : The term 'express' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ express
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (express:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\testuser\testme>
```

This has been installed globally.

Any ideas?

Comment: please check C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm for the express executable (should be two files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `PATH` to be sure it includes the location for globally installed modules.

At a command prompt:

1. type `npm ls -g --depth=0` and note the directory printed on the first line of output
2. type `PATH` to see if the directory found in step `#1` is in the path...

If (when) the `npm` global install directory is missing from your `PATH`, adding it should fix the problem.

See this other StackOverflow question as a reference: [Grunt on Windows 8: 'grunt' is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135561/grunt-on-windows-8-grunt-is-not-recognized)

Comment: Nice, just what I needed. Works great. Thanks. Strange it wasn't added by default.