# Grunt.js Installation Issue - Command Not Found

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, git, gruntjs

I'm trying to get `grunt.js` set up on my work machine. Now I've managed to get it set up at home, so I pushed my repository, then cloned it on my work machine, however despite troubleshooting this to death I've always run into the same issue when I come to try and run the command on my work computer;

```
sh.exe": grunt: command not found
```

So some background and explanation;

- I'm using `Aptana 3.0` and running all my commands through the terminal. (This applies to my home and work computer)
- I cloned the "working" repository and put it in a folder on my work machine, so I have my     `package.json` and `gruntfile.js` files inside said directory. These work fine on my home computer and I am able to run the watch task set up in my `gruntfile.js` successfully at home.
- I've run `npm install grunt-cli -g` and `npm install` inside my project on my WORK computer and installation has been successful each time. My only error messages on either are a lack of description and a repository field which, to my knowledge these aren't mandatory?
- The node modules folder inside my repository indicates I have the following installed (as per my package.json)

  - `grunt`
  - `grunt-contrib-compass`
  - `grunt-contrib-uglify`
  - `grunt-contrib-watch`
  - `matchdep`

Now I'm pretty green to this command line stuff, so I may have overlooked something very obvious but I feel like I've tried every guide going to get this thing to work.

Despite running through the getting started steps/installing grunt documentation repeatedly, it seems no matter what I do the terminal will not pick up grunt as a recognized command.

Am I stupid or is this some other issue?

EDIT 1: contents of my package.json:

`{
    "name" : "xxxxxxxxx",
    "version" : "xxxx",
    "dependencies" : {
        "grunt":"~0.4.1",
        "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
        "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.2",
        "matchdep": "~0.1.2"
    }
}`

Comment: Have you read through this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19137584/463205

Comment: @athms Fantastic, I had no idea about setting PATH variables before reading that, hadn't come across that one, thanks a lot for your help, it now recognizes grunt as a command - sorted!

Comment: @athms add your post as an answer - I think it should be accepted

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyShcherbak, I've just added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you are using the Aptana Terminal, which needs the PATH variable to work out what is meant by grunt etc. A normal cmd prompt would work fine with the command `npm install grunt-cli -g` but in this context the terminal is unaware of what `grunt` is.

As per the following existing answer, you need to set up your Windows PATH variable to make the Aptana Terminal aware of the npm directory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19137584/463205

`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Closing the terminal and reopening it after setting the PATH correctly should enable you to run the command successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Try to run

```
npm install grunt-cli -g
```

On your home computer.
`-g` means - install Grunt globally (not in the project node_modules folder), so it'll add grunt command to the bin folder which is used by nodejs console ( and you need to run node.js command prompt, not just arbitrary cmd)

Comment: I had done that on both computers, it was not setting the PATH variable to node. Having gone through the article above and added the `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm` to my path variable its now recognizing the command :)

Comment: That's because you are using the Aptana Terminal, which needs the PATH variable to work out what is meant by grunt etc. A normal cmd prompt would work fine with the command `npm install grunt-cli -g`