# Trouble in installing Grunt in my windows machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to install grunt-cli in my pc globally by command

`npm install -g grunt-cli`

after this I am not getting any error. But when I try to run grunt command I am getting error.

Screen shot has been attached.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Grunt on Windows 8: 'grunt' is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135561/grunt-on-windows-8-grunt-is-not-recognized).

You need to correct `PATH` from environment variable.

Comment: is correct above. There is issue with grunt installation path as well.

Comment: Is your problem fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have installed grunt but not configured it. You will have to create a Gruntfile.js which is read by grunt and it should have a default task. This default task will be run when you are typing "grunt". And this file should be exactly in the folder from where you are running "grunt" command.
For a kick start go through the following url:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/08/grunt-introduction/

It gives a very easy and minimized introduction to getting started with grunt avoiding all the complexities which you can explore later once you are comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Kishore,

It looks like grunt isn't in your path. Try running `path=%PATH%;%APPDATA%\npm` in your shell.