# Install Node Configuration

Tags: node.js, global

Hi  i installed node and npm. Next i want to configure global server called "http-server". Everything install fine. But when i want to run "http-server" i get error.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>http-server 'http-server' is not recognized as an
internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

This my CODE in CMD

```
C:\Users\Matthew>cd C:\

C:\>npm install --global http-server
C:\Users\Matthew\npm-global\http-server -> C:\Users\Matthew\npm-global\node_modules\http-server\bin\http-server

C:\Users\Matthew\npm-global\hs -> C:\Users\Matthew\npm-global\node_modules\http-server\bin\http-server

+ http-server@0.10.0
added 23 packages in 36.321s
```

[PHOTO CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkIF8.png)

My PATHS are good:
C:\Users\Matthew>PATH
PATH=C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Roaming\npm

Why this command create folder npm-global? Why its not installed in AppData~

Please help! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grunt on Windows 8: 'grunt' is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135561/grunt-on-windows-8-grunt-is-not-recognized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a answer:

```
npm config set prefix C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm
```