# why do i get this error with install npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line, node-modules

I am trying to create a new app in react and getting this error:

> 'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> 7.13.0

In the Environment Variables this is the path:

User variables path:

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\dvirb\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\dvirb\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\dvirb\AppDaata\Roaming\npm;%USERPROFILE%.dotnet\tools;

System variables path:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH;\nodejs;";%JAVA_HOME%\bin";C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;\C:\Users\dvirb\AppDaata\Roaming\npm;\C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;

Anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: can you write down the command you are running?

Comment: Sure, npx create-react-app pricestock

Comment: take a look here and try the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47541116/7857368)